# jQuery horizontal scrolling display

Tags: jquery, animation, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a horizontal scroller using jQuery. I have it working using the following

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    content = $('#scroll-content');


wrapper.bind('mousemove', function(e){

    var wrapper_width = wrapper.width(),
        content_width = content.width();
        //wrapper and content width

    var tmp  = e.pageX * (content.outerWidth() - wrapper.outerWidth()) / wrapper.outerWidth();
    //calculate new left margin

    content.css({ 'margin-left': '-'+tmp+'px' });
    //set margin according

    /*content.animate({
        'margin-left': '-'+tmp+'px'
    }, 30, 'easeOutSine');*/
});
```

Every mousemove event I calculate the new left margin, the slider spans 100% width of the screen.

This works, but I have two problems. It seems bad practise to be calling a calculation on every mousemove event as there are hundreds. Is there a better way, maybe using timers?

Another question, when the user first hovers the slider it jumps into place, I tried to use animate so that the slider would slide down to the correct position, but didn't seem to work. (commented at the bottom)

any help with these problems would be great. Thanks

Comment: What is the desired animation? A constant scroll or scroll on some event?

Comment: instead of jumping to the correct position, i just want it to scroll to the correct position, i created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/letsgojuno/RkbP6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ben Alman's Throttle Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

And then do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        content = $('#scroll-content');

    wrapper.bind('mouseenter mousemove', $.throttle(200, mousemove));

    function mousemove(e) {
        var wrapper_width = wrapper.outerWidth(),
            content_width = content.outerWidth();
        //calculate new left margin
        var tmp = e.pageX * (content_width - wrapper_width) / wrapper_width;

        content.stop().animate({
            'margin-left': '-' + tmp + 'px'
        }, 'fast', 'easeOutSine');
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/RkbP6/1/

Comment: awesome, thats exactly what I was looking for, I knew I'd seen a throttling plugin before, just couldn't remember where. Thanks Petersen

Answer (score 1):

I knew I had seen something similar in terms of throttling. John Resig posted a blog about problems with twitters infinite scroll. I used his solution in the following.

Here's the blog post for anyone interested.

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        content = $('#scroll-content'),
        did_move = false,
        g_event;

    wrapper.bind('mouseenter mousemove', function(e) {
        did_move = true;
        g_event = e;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (did_move) {
            did_move = false;
            //reset move bool
        }

        var wrapper_width = wrapper.outerWidth(),
            content_width = content.outerWidth();
            //update wrapper and content widths

        var tmp = g_event.pageX * (content_width - wrapper_width) / wrapper_width;
        //recalculate margin-left

        content.stop().animate({
            'margin-left': '-' + tmp + 'px'
        }, 'fast', 'easeOutSine');
        //animate into place.

    }, 150);
});
```